# __proto__ and instanceof

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

I am having a little trouble understanding why `Result` is false in the following code.

Other objects in the library that are required to have a size will check if the size parameter is an instance of `InterfaceKit.Core.Size`. Currently, `instanceof` is returning false.

```
var InterfaceKit = {
    Core : {
        Size: function( i_Width, i_Height ){
            Object.defineProperties(this, {
                m_Width : {
                    value: Number( i_Width ) ? Number( i_Width ) : 0
                    , writable: true
                }
                , m_Height : {
                    value: Number( i_Height ) ? Number( i_Height ) : 0
                    , writable: true
                }

            }); 

            this.__proto__ = {
                SetWidth: function( i_Width ){
                    if( Number( i_Width ) )
                        this.m_Width = Number( i_Width ); 

                }
                , GetWidth: function(){
                    return this.m_Width; 
                }
                , SetHeight: function( i_Height ){
                    if( Number( i_Height ) )
                        this.m_Height = Number( i_Height ); 

                }
                , GetHeight: function(){
                    return this.m_Height; 
                }

            };

            this.__proto__.constructor = InterfaceKit.Core.Size; 

        }

    }

}; 

var Result = (new InterfaceKit.Core.Size( 10, 10 ) instanceof InterfaceKit.Core.Size); //false
```

Comment: Note that `__proto__` is was never supposed to be visible, and this won't work in IE or Opera

Comment: This is a redacted example of something I'm trying to write. So far, I've noticed that if I comment out 'this.__proto__ = {};,' the expressions resolves to true.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do anyways?

Comment: Set the `prototype` (don't use `__proto__`) and its `constructor` outside of the function, then instanceof will be true. By redefining the prototype of the function, the instance is no more the same as the function originally provides. Also by resetting `__proto__`, you change every object instance, and it will never be the instance of any function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its `prototype` chain the prototype property of a constructor.

In other words...

```
// an objects prototype chains has this as the root
object.__proto__ // set to: {}

// the prototype property of the constructor
A.B.prototype // unmodified prototype, some object set by JS engine. Probably: {}

// Equivalent objects are not equal, because they are different objects
{} === {} // false
```

Therefore the constructor's prototype is not in the prototype chain of the object. Which means it is *not* an `instanceof` the constructor, even if that constructor did "construct" that object.

---

But really, just don't use `__proto__`.

```
var A = {
    B: function() {}
};
A.B.prototype = {};

var Result = (new A.B() instanceof A.B); // true
```

Comment: Another question for you out of curiosity... How come I can do this: `this.__proto__ += {};`?

Comment: @NathanWehr stop it. Modifying `__proto__` is one thing, coercing it to string is another.

Comment: @NathanWehr let's just say you'll end up with the string `"[object Object][object Object]"` as your prototype.

Comment: Since when was the `+=` operator only used for strings? If you can use it on strings and numbers, and everything in javascript is an object, why not on object literals? That's my question...

Comment: @NathanWehr `+=` will coerce to strings unless both operands are numeric or boolean. There's no such thing as object addition. Try out `({}+{})`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

From [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/):

> **11.8.6 The instanceof operator**
>
> The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. If rval does not have a [[HasInstance]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 7. *Return the result of calling the [[HasInstance]] internal method of rval with argument lval.*
>
> ...
>
> **15.3.5.3 [[HasInstance]] (V)**
>
> Assume F is a Function object.
>
> When the [[HasInstance]] internal method of F is called with value V, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If V is not an object, return false.
> 2. Let O be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of F with property name "prototype".
> 3. If Type(O) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Repeat
>
>    - Let V be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of V.
>    - If V is null, return false.
>    - *If O and V refer to the same object, return true.*
>
> NOTE Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind have a different implementation of [[HasInstance]] defined in 15.3.4.5.3.

Basically, `instanceof` returns `true` iff the left operand has the right operand's prototype in its inheritance chain: `l.__proto__ === r.prototype || l.__proto__.__proto__ === r.prototype || ...`

Since the left operand of your object has its prototype overriden (`__proto__` is a proprietary alias for the internal `[[prototype]]` property) and not assigned by Javascript, `new A.B()` no longer inherits from `A.B.prototype`, as it normally would, and thus is not an `instanceof` `A.B`

Comment: Pretty sure it uses `===` for comparing `__proto__` to the constructor prototype, and not `==`. If it was coercing the quality check, the original post's code should have returned `true`.

Comment: @AlexWayne Not sure `==` is incorrect since all compared entities are objects. Modified to use `===` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this to be the best solution:

```
var InterfaceKit {
    Core: {
        Size : function( i_Width, i_Height ){
            this.__prototype__ = Object.getPrototypeOf( this ); 

            var m_Width  = 0; 
            var m_Height = 0; 

            this.__prototype__.SetWidth  = function( i_Width ){}; 
            this.__prototype__.GetWidth  = function(){}; 
            this.__prototype__.SetHeight = function( i_Height ){}; 
            this.__prototype__.GetHeight = function(){}; 

            {
                 this.SetWidth( i_Width ); 
                 this.SetHeight( i_Height ); 
            }

        }

    }

}; 

var Result = (new InterfaceKit.Core.Size( 10, 10 ) instanceof InterfaceKit.Core.Size); // true
```